# OIM11gR2PS3 Dynamic Manual Fulfillment Task Assignment

Tags: soa, identity-management, oim, fulfillment

Usually when a Disconnected Application Instance is provisioned to a user, the manual fulfillment tasks are by default assigned to "SYSTEM ADMINISTRATORS" Role. We can modify it to any other role directly in SOA Composer so that the Fulfillment tasks are assigned to the newly Updated role. We can also have different rules in place for different application instances.

But the scenario is like We have a Role associated with a access policy which will provision a Disconnected Application Instance to the user upon provisioning the role. The Access Policy is also associated with some entitlements which will require manual fulfillment tasks to be assigned to particular fulfillment role which differs for different roles.

How do we dynamically fetch the Fulfillment Role in order to assign the task to them. I understand we should achieve it using the Oracle Business Rules. But How do I get the catalog attributes in the DisconnectedProvisioning composite.

I am a beginner in SOA - Workflow implementation. So please provide some detailed answers.

Thanks,
Srini

Comment: Hi Srini I think you can create DVM lookup to store the entitlement data and its corrosponding user to whome the task needs to be assigned.

Comment: Hi Srini did you tried DVM thing? the other solution to this a custom java class which will read OIM Catalog attributes and return the role value

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign a role to the Fulfillment Roles on the Disconnected App and it's separate entitlements in the catalog.

Then when the Access Policy triggers  First a Provision Task should be generated for the Fulfiller role on the application instance,  then once that is completed a Grant Entitlement task will be created for the fulfiller roles associated with each entitlement.